# TypeScript imports react component in ES6

Tags: reactjs, meteor, typescript

I have an issue with importing a component written in ES6 files to TS component. Basically what I am doing is

```
import FormGroup from "/imports/ui/formGroup"
```

And it throws error `error TS2307: Cannot find module '/imports/ui/formGroup'`

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

But if I add this to `compilerOptions`

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "*": [
    "*"
  ]
}
```

and do this (use `imports` instead of `/imports`)

```
import FormGroup from "imports/ui/formGroup"
```

It is perfectly compiled. But the issue is since I am running Meteor, it doesn't recognise the `imports` path, but `/imports` does.

What could possibly the suggested way to import my existing ES6 components without having to create declaration file for each component so that I can incrementally transition to TS?

Comment: Did you try setting `include` property. ex.  `"include": ["src/**/*"]`

Answer (score 0):

If your component is js/jsx file, you have to add `allowJs: true` to your `compilerOptions`. Hope I understood your question correctly.